# JWT connection between Angular 6 and Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, angular, laravel, rest, jwt

I am new to Angular and to Laravel.
So if I am stupid, just say it ;)

I have created a login form in Angular and a authentication method in Laravel. 
I have tested the Laravel API with Postman and it worked. Authentication, registration, getting and using the JWT.

But my Angular App doesn't seem to send the right post request to Laravel. 
Unfortunately I don't know how to display the send request in Angular or in Laravel.

The JSON return is:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/api/login 400 (Bad Request)
error: "invalid_credentials"
```

I get this return every time, even if I put in the correct credentials.

This is the authentication method in Laravel:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

This is the auth.service.ts in Angular:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  login(credentials) {
   return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login', JSON.stringify(credentials));
  }

  logout() {
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And the login.component.ts:

```
import { AuthService } from './../services/auth.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
    invalidLogin: boolean;
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService) { }

    signIn(credentials) {
        //let request = '?email=' + credentials['email'] + '&password=' + credentials['password'];
        let request = credentials;
        this.authService.login(request).subscribe(result => {
            if (result) {
              this.router.navigate(['/']);
            } else {
                this.invalidLogin = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here the login form login.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <form #loginf="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="signIn(loginf.value.login)">
                <div ngModelGroup="login" #login="ngModelGroup">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger animated bounceIn delay-2s" *ngIf="email.touched && password.touched && (!login.valid)">
                        Die eingegeben Daten sind nicht korrekt.
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="invalidLogin" class="alert alert-danger">Invalid username and/or password.</div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input required ngModel ng-model="email.text" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" #email="ngModel" placeholder="E-Mail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input required ngModel name="password" type="password" class="form-control" #password="ngModel" placeholder="Passwort">
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        <a>Passwort vergessen</a>
                        <a>Ich brauche Hilfe vom Kunden-Support</a>
                    </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!loginf.valid">LOGIN</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the chrome network tab to see if the same authorization headers you sent with postman are being sent by your application? Are there any CORS errors in the console?

Comment: I have fixed the CORS issue with a laravel package. I will check the otherone!